# Store hierarchy number pattern like 1.1.1 in numeric format in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, logic, number-formatting

I have a pattern number which uniquely identifies a record in database. Here are some examples for the pattern numbers -

```
AB1
AB1.1
AB1.2
AB1.2.1
AB1.2.2
AB2
AB2.1
AB2.1.1
```

Currently these are stored as string in database. I am also sorting based on this column. I'm using `varchar` as datatype for this column but it's not efficient for sorting and data retrieval. I am investigating to convert this pattern to numeric somehow or have table structure in slightly different way. But I did not find any way to represent it in number.Please suggest me if you have any idea.

One idea that I have is create a number based on below formula -

```
1000000
  10000
   1000
```

adding this and use this number to represent -

```
1.1.1
```

But if there is any other efficient way please suggest

Comment: I don't think there's a datatype for what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yeah but if there is any logic which I can use in Function to recreate a string from number and convert string to a number or use the logic in Calculated column.

Comment: ...Why do you think `VARCHAR` is bad for sorting/searching?  Are you experiencing some sort of bottleneck?  Would an index help?  If you have a variable length prefix, you need VARCHAR (or to strip blanks before concatenation, which is usually _more_ work).  If I was going to store this separated, I might use `VARCHAR` to store each part (major version, minor version, etc), which should help make certain rollups easier too.  If you just want a plain id, just setup an autoincrement column.  Oh, what DB?

Comment: If you're using a suitable version (and can adapt to it's format) there's a built in [`hierarchyid`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx) type that sorts in the expected fashion.

Comment: Oh, now I think I get it.  What is your _expected_ sort order?  (@Damien_The_Unbeliever - it should sort the way he lists them normally, right?)

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - `hierarchyid` sorts so that children sort immediately after their parent and before the parent's next sibling. (and so on down the structure)

Comment: if AB is always fixed then you can remove AB but this bad idea.T'row new id can generate like CD.In given situation what is there is good let it be varchar.you can create one extra column with int identity(1,1)which can help you in sorting .

Another bad idea is to create  separate column for major,minor etc as int.

Comment: Hi KumarHarsh, AB is fixed, I can remove it from DB.. what should be the value of identity(1,1) column and how can it map to 1.1 or 1.2

Comment: create one dummy table with  column  identity(1,1) and anothr column with pattern column varchar.SEE ITS behaviour yourself .
Oh one more idea.called newBigIntColumn store value like 
1.1.1=>10101 (replace dot with zero)
2.1=>201
show value which will fail my idea .

Comment: @Clockwise-Muse - I am using SQL Server 2008 DB

Comment: @Damien - hierarchyid seems to be available only with 2012

Comment: @KumarHarsh - If I create Identity Column but to store in the table at first glance I would need data in sorted order. Also Inserts would create an issue. Regarding other idea of replacing dot with zero, it would fail if I have zero in my original pattern like 10.10.10.. here which zero is for dot would be confusing. Would you suggest using 3 columns to store this if I say pattern is fix like XX.XX.XX

Comment: Sorry guys .. hieracrchygrid is available with 2008 also... I am searching for usage examples of it.

Answer (score -1):

using 3 column is good idea like major (int),minor (int),minor1 (int).
be sure that it is not null and default is 0.it will be easy to retrieve.Now in c# property define get accessor formula.

```
public int Major {get;set}
public int Minor {get;set}
public int Minor1 {get;set}
public string Version 
{

     get
    {
    return "AB"+Major.ToString()+Minor.ToString()+Minor1.ToString();
    }

}
```

Bur first decide that if you go by this way then qhat all queries you have then decide .